# Session cookie across task pane and dialog

Tags: session, session-cookies, office-js, office-addins

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) describes the authentication process for an Office add-in.  It states that, for the dialog:

> It does not share the same session storage as the task pane

This does not seem to match my experience.  This is what I'm doing:

- Task pane opens dialog with `displayDialogAsync`
- User logs in with the dialog and a session cookie is set in the dialog.
- Without passing any info to the parent (`messageParent` is not used), the task pane then has the session cookie set.

Is the documentation here have a mistake?  Or is the session shared on some platforms but not on other platforms?  I'm on Mac with Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line in the documentation refers to the [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) property. Cookies and server-side storage can be shared between the dialog and the host page. I'll get the documentation clarified.

Comment: Thanks Rick, much appreciated!